# GitLab Pipeline tag stopped triggering stage marked only:tags

Tags: triggers, tags, gitlab, pipeline

We have a GitLab pipeline that gets triggered from another pipeline. This pipeline has two stages, each of which runs in a separate instance of the pipeline. Both of these stages function correctly.

The first stage reacts to a trigger. It finds a version tag in the repo, increments it by one, and applies that tag back to the current project.

The second stage runs in response to a new tag, in a new instance of the pipeline. This stage also functions perfectly when it runs.

The problem is that the second stage no longer runs after the first stage runs successfully. It was working fine until two weeks ago. Key parts of the pipeline are reproduced below.

PROBLEM SUMMARY

- If you use the trigger that fires the 'createtag' stage, the 'createtag' stage runs, creates the tag, pushes it to the repo, and then the 'deploy' stage with only:tags DOES NOT RUN. But it used to, up until two weeks ago.

PIPELINE STILL RESPONDS TO OTHER METHODS OF SETTING TAGS

- If you create a tag from a GIT command prompt and push it to the
  repo, the 'deploy' stage with only:tags works.
- If you create a tag from the GitLab project main page via the Create New | New Tag dropdown option, the 'deploy' stage with only:tags works.

ONE OTHER BIT OF KEY INFORMATION

The 'createtag' stage also stopped working two weeks ago. Turns out the token tied to the trigger was invalid, and the user that owned the token was no longer with the company, and GitLab showed 'Blocked' next to the user in the Members tab.

Taking ownership of the trigger/token with a current user re-enabled the token. With that, the 'createtag' stage started running again. The problem is that the 'deploy' stage still does not get fired when the 'createtag' stage pushes the new tag to the repo.

Any ideas on what happened and how to get the 'deploy' stage to start responding to the actions of the 'createtag' stage again? I'm fairly certain it has to do with permissions around the user who left.

```
variables:
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"

stages:
  - createtag
  - deploy

# When receiving a trigger to build, tag the repository with the next numeric
# build version. This should kick off the next build pipeline for deployment.
increment_version:
  stage: createtag
  script:
    # For brevity, logic to connect to repo, get tags, set $NEW_TAG are omitted. They work just fine

    # Create new tag and push to repo
    - git tag $NEW_TAG master
    - git push --tags

  only:
    - triggers

# When a tagged build is received, execute script
deploy_to_somewhere:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - [Do Something Here]
  only:
    - tags
```

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` to see if I could get a job to tag a build which would then cause another instance of the same pipeline; and the following does that (with the personal access token redacted).

I had to add a trigger token and a personal access token to make this test work.

This worked as expected -- I would hit the pipeline with `curl` to trigger it, and then it would create a tag, and that would set off another pipeline which would run the deployment.

Here is the complete working `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
createtag:
  script:
    - git config --global user.email "me@example.com"
    - git config --global user.name "My Name"
    - git tag -m 'tag message' $(date +%s) origin/master
    - git remote add mygitlab https://oauth2:__MYTOKEN__@gitlab.com/atsaloli/trigger-test.git
    - git push --tags mygitlab
  only:
    - triggers

deploy_to_somewhere:
  script:
    - echo run deploy script
  only:
    - tags
```

and a screenshot showing the two pipeline instances:

[image]

So, what you described can definitely work -- I would look a bit closer at your system to see if each part works as it should -- the `git` commands you gave, for example, I don't see how they would work...

Where you have:

```
  # Create new tag and push to repo
    - git tag $NEW_TAG master
    - git push --tags
```

I found that did not work for me.

First, "master" was not a known git reference:

```
 $ git tag $(date +%s) master
 fatal: Failed to resolve 'master' as a valid ref.
```

Then, "origin/master" worked, but I had to set my identity:

```
 $ git tag -m 'tag message' $(date +%s) origin/master
 *** Please tell me who you are.
 Run
   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
 to set your account's default identity.
 Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
 fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@runner-72989761-project-3569621-concurrent-0.(none)')
```

Finally, I had to provide a gitlab-ci-token:

```
 $ git config --global user.email "me@example.com"
 $ git config --global user.name "My Name"
 $ git tag -m 'tag message' $(date +%s) origin/master
 $ git push --tags
 remote: You are not allowed to upload code.
 fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.com/atsaloli/test.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

So once I handled all that, I found that I could auto-tag the repo which would cause another instance of the pipeline to run.

Comment: Aleksey, thanks for building a test pipeline and verifying the overall functionality: trigger causes stage 1 to run, and stage 1's work causes another instance of the pipeline to run stage 2. I have verified that each part of my pipeline works as it should, and updated the original post to make that more clear.

The problem is that the first stage no longer causes the 2nd stage, 2nd instance of the pipeline to run.

I'm considering removing the 2nd stage, and then recreating it, to see if that somehow gets it going again. Certainly still open to other ideas.

Comment: Interesting problem! What if you were to run my test pipeline (after updating the token and Git URL to target your test project)?  I would expect that it would work (1st stage should cause the 2nd stage, 2nd instance of the pipeline to run).  Are you in a self-hosted GitLab?